# Log-concavity of lattice-functions and convolution

Tags: co.combinatorics, convexity, convolution

I was looking at the definition of log-concavity:

> A function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said log-concave
> iff $F(x)\geq 0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and
> $$F(x)^\lambda F(y)^{1-\lambda}\leq F(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)$$ $\forall
> > x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

And, according to [Brascamp-Lieb](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-55925-9_34),

> If $F$ is a log-concave function in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ and
> $F:(x,y)\rightarrow F(x,y)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and
> $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $G(x)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}F(x,y)dy$ is
> a log-concave function in $\mathbb{R}^m$. The convolution of two log-concave functions is log-concave.

This leads me to the following two questions:

1. Is there any definition of what would be the concavity of functions defined $\mathbb{Z}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?
2. Is there a discrete analogous of the two theorems?

When I say a discrete analogous I mean substitute $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ by $\mathbb{Z}^{n+m}$ and then, as a consequence state, that a discrete convolution of two log-concave functions is also log-concave.

Comment: Good question. Might want to look at the notions of L-convex and M-convex functions in the book "Discrete Convex Analysis" by Murota.

Comment: Thank you! I'm posting the link here for those who want to take a look too. https://www.comp.tmu.ac.jp/kzmurota/paper/HIMSummerSchool15Murota.pdf

Comment: Nice. I was referring to the 400+ page book but this review article looks like a good summary.